# Iterate through objects in JSON

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate through the follow json file

[[image]]

In order to access the rank of each item in api.standings[0] so I can create a new table cell with the rank key.

This is my my current code:

```
data.api.standings[0].forEach(elements => {

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');

        tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + data.api.standings[0].rank + '</td>';

        table.appendChild(tr);

    });
```

However I am getting undefined in the cell.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your data structure [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Have you called the API properly? Like in a Promise or Ajax call or Http Request?

Comment: just replace ```data.api.standings[0].rank``` by ```elements.rank```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is correct, you are iterating through the array `standings[0]`. In which case, you need to adjust how you reference the objects in the `innerHTML` assignment statement.

```
data.api.standings[0].forEach(elements => {

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + elements.rank + '</td>';

    table.appendChild(tr);

});
```

Comment: To expand, the reason the cell is undefined is that it expects the value of standings[0].rank, which is undefined.

Comment: Correct. `data.api.standings[0]` is an array of objects. The current object being iterated over is `elements` so that variable should be used in the body of the `forEach` callback.